# Help with Removing SOQL from FOR Loop in Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, soql

Need help moving a SOQL statement outside a FOR loop to prevent hitting limits. Scenario here is that there are two fields on our records, Quoted By User and Sold By User. Any time a record is updated and marked as "sold", I need to query who each of these users are for the purpose of tracking and counting. Below is what I have so far, but this is with SOQL inside my FOR Loop. Thanks everyone.

```
public void updateRepsSales(map<Id,Case> oldMap, list<Case> newList)
{
    Employee__c newSoldEm = new Employee__c();
    Employee__c newQuotedEm = new Employee__c();
    List<Sale__c> newSales = new List<Sale__c>();
    for(Case currCase : newList)
    {
      //if the current case is now sold
        if((currCase.Status != oldMap.get(currCase.Id).Status) && currCase.Status == 'Sold')
        {
            if(currCase.Quoted_By__c != currCase.Sold_By__c)
            {
                //select the quoted by and sold by user and assign it to employee record
                Employee__c newQuotedEmp = [SELECT Id FROM Employee__c WHERE OwnerId =: currCase.Quoted_By__c];
                Employee__c newSoldEmp = [SELECT Id FROM Employee__c WHERE OwnerId =: currCase.Sold_By__c];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll use a standard aggregate-query-update pattern:

```
Map<Id, Employee__c> employees = new Map<Id, Employee__c>();
Case[] selected = new Case[0];
for(Case record: newList) {
    if(record.Status != oldMap.get(record.Id).Status && record.Status == 'sold' && record.Quoted_By__c != record.Sold_By__c) {
        selected.add(record);
        employees.put(record.Quoted_By__c, null);
        employees.put(record.Sold_By__c, null);
    }
}
for(Employee__c record:[SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM Employee__c WHERE OwnerId IN :employees.keySet()) {
    employees.put(record.OwnerId, record);
}
for(Case record: selected) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A pattern could go like this:

- try to select all employes in one query on top

  - loop through the result and add them into a `map<Id,Employee__c>` where you set the key to OwnerId
- and then use the map inside the main loop instead of the query
- since you have the OwnerId as key, it's easy to access the matching record.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like this is an issue with [Bulkification](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice%3A_Bulkify_Your_Code)

The key concept is to assume that your "newList" and "oldMap" will have several records in them (up to 200 I believe).

With this in mind when you are comparing a new case to its old case instead of directly SOQLing for the Employee__cs that are needed, you collect the information that you will need to collect the Employee__cs.

With what is shown here one of my first changes would be to change

```
 Employee__c newQuotedEmp = [SELECT Id FROM Employee__c WHERE OwnerId =: currCase.Quoted_By__c];
 Employee__c newSoldEmp = [SELECT Id FROM Employee__c WHERE OwnerId =: currCase.Sold_By__c];
```

to

```
quotedByOwners.add(currCase.Quoted_By__c);
soldByOwners.add(currCase.Sold_By__c);
```

(Where quotedByOwners and soldByOwners are each a Set < Id >)

And after the for loop is completed I would retrieve all records that need to be processed.:

```
List<Employee__c> employeesToBeProcessed = [SELECT Id 
 FROM Employee__c 
 WHERE OwnerId IN :quotedByOwners 
   OR OwnerId IN :soldByOwners];
```

OR depending on your business case:

```
List<Employee__c> employeesToBeProcessedSold = [SELECT Id 
 FROM Employee__c 
 WHERE OwnerId IN :soldByOwners];

List<Employee__c> employeesToBeProcessedQuoted = [SELECT Id 
 FROM Employee__c 
 WHERE OwnerId IN :quotedByOwners];
```

Now that all the records that you need have been retrieved you can process them as necessary. This may include changing every single employee or associated each employee to its original case for more granular processing